# Websites & Web Applications Using Erlang

Tags: web-applications, web, erlang

I was wondering if people could post some examples of interesting websites and web apps that were built with Erlang?

I can start with a few Erlang based sites:

- twitterfall.com - Waterfall of Tweets
- vimagi.com - Cooperative painting.
- twoorl.com - Twitter clone.
- dayfindr.com - Collaborative meeting scheduling.
- beerriot.com - Beer enthusiast site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mine: [shapesmith.net](http://shapesmith.net)

- [Heroku](http://heroku.com/how) uses it for their routing mesh (web infrastructure)
- [HyperNumbers](http://www.hypernumbers.com/)
- [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) (not a web app, but used in web stacks)
- [Campfire](http://campfirenow.com/) uses it for their [poller](http://www.37signals.com/svn/posts/1728-nuts-bolts-campfire-loves-erlang)
- [Smarkets](http://www.smarkets.com/)
- [Webmachine](https://github.com/basho/webmachine)
- [Nitrogen Web Framework](http://nitrogenproject.com/)

Answer (score 3):

[CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) - an apache project, document server.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook Chat has its [important backend bits written in Erlang](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=14218138919).

Answer (score 2):

[ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im) (a Jabber server) is a pretty big one. It isn't a website but with its http-bind and http-poll and web admin modules it is technically a web application.

Answer (score 2):

The toy twitter search mash up site I hacked up a while back [ihatevans](http://ihatevans.com/)

I even threw the source up on [github](http://github.com/madlep/ihatevans/tree/master)

Pretty bare bones Mochiweb based web app.

Answer (score 0):

- [World Forge](http://www.worldforge.org/) MMO
- [Yaws](http://yaws.hyber.org/) webserver
- [Wings 3D](http://www.wings3d.com/) Modeler